# How do I display the max function i created in python

Tags: python

I have to get userinputs of ints and store them in a array, and print the max number in the list. But I had to create my own max function. Im not sure what steps to take to implement it into my code.

```
def getInt(prompt):
    n = int
    done = False
    while not done:
        try:
            n = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("I was expecting a number, please try again...")
        if n == 0:
            done = True

    return n

def maxNum(l):
    maxi = [0]
    for num in l:
        if maxi > num:
            maxi = num
    return maxi

def result():
    print("The maxium value is: " + maxNum(i))

def main():
    num = []
    i = 0
    done = False
    while not done:
        num = getInt("Please enter an integer < 0 to finish >: ")
        if num == 0:
            done = True
        results = maxNum(i)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is currently happening in your code that is not working as expected? Also provide any error messages you are receiving. What inputs are you giving your code, and what is the output you are getting that does not meet your expectation? Please edit the question to include these details.

Comment: (based on your lack of explanation, it seems like you are looking to get the output somehow) looks like you forgot to call the function. call `main()` at the end of the file

Comment: I keep getting a "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable" also not sure how to exactly go about getting the max

Comment: Your program seems to have several errors that Python would probably not even accept. I suggest you iron out the errors first. Bugs arising from scoping of variables can come next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code does exactly what you want.

```
def getInt(prompt):
    try:
        n = int(input(prompt))
        return n
    except ValueError:
        print("I was expecting a number, please try again...")
        getInt()

def maxNum(lst):
    if not lst:     # if list is empty
        return None

    max_elem = lst[0]
    for x in lst:
        if x > max_elem:
            max_elem = x
    return max_elem


def main():
    nums = []
    while True:
        num = getInt("Please enter an integer < 0 to finish >: ")
        if num == 0:
            break
        nums.append(num)
    result = maxNum(nums)
    print("The maxium value is: " + str(result))

main()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I knew I needed to put .append but was not sure where to place it at. Much appreciated

Comment: @HoseaG Are you sure? Testing this with non-integer input yields an error. The OP is forgetting to pass the `prompt` parameter to the recursive call to `getInt()` in `getInt()`.

Answer (score 0):

python support built-in `max` function

```
max([1,2,3]) # return 3
```

and Your code is totally wrong.

if you want to input array of integers, getInt may be like this.

```
def getInt():
    array = []
    while True:
    x = int(input('message'))
        if x == 0: break
        array.append(x)
    return array
```

and main code will be

```
array = getInt()
max_value = max(array)
print (max_value)
```

if you want your own max function, it can be

```
def max_func(array):
    max_val = array[0]
    for val in array:
        if val > max_val: max_val = val
    return max_val
```

Comment: They specified in the question, that they are writing their own `method`

Comment: Im not allowed to use the built in max function. I have to create my own

Comment: append custom max_function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed version of your `maxNum` function:

```
def maxNum(l):
    if not l:
        return None # or return whatever you want if user did not input anything
    maxi = l[0] # it expects 'l' to be an array!
    for num in l[1:]:
        if maxi > num:
            maxi = num
    return maxi
```

Let's also fix your `getInt` function:

```
def getInt(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("I was expecting a number, please try again...")
```

Finally, your "main" function needs the following fix:

```
def main():
    num = []
    n = 1
    while n != 0:
        n = getInt("Please enter an integer < 0 to finish >: ") # store user input into n - do not overwrite num!
        num.append(n) # append each user value to the list num
    results = maxNum(num) # pass the entire *list* to maxNum
```